# Headless CMS – why is it better than a simple database connection?

Tags: web-development, cms, database

Ok, I read **plenty** of articles on **headless/decoupled** CMS systems, however I can't wrap my head around how it should be better than a simple database connection.

From what I got so far, the main advantage of a headless CMS is that it's not connected to a specific front-end, so that the content can be used and accessed by different devices like watches, browsers, apps, IoT, etc.

So **headless** would be:

```
back end –> stores content in database –> API –> different front-ends for watches, browsers, apps, IoT etc.
```

And **traditional** would be:

```
back end –> stores content in database –> different front-ends for watches, browsers, apps, IoT, etc.
```

(?)

**My Question:** why to implement the extra API layer, when every device front-end can just simply pull the data from a database anyways?

By simply pulling the data from a database, you're also not restricted to a specific front-end programming language, you can use whatever language you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your comparison could use an extra piece for the rendering aspect.

For “traditional,” distributed content management systems, that might be part of the content manager (back end) side of the system as in:

`back end –> stores content in database –> content manager rendering/templating –> different front-ends for watches, browsers, apps, IoT, etc.`

I’d say “content-as-data” is a big part of the headless CMS definition, whether that’s JSON, XML, or some markdown format. For frontend or any application developers using a headless CMS, they’re working less with rendered or templates HTML and more with some meaningful content model, in their programming language of choice.

As a consumer of such a service, you don’t have to understand the content data model and relationships as much as some raw database structure.

The question why API over database is probably broader than just in a CMS context. APIs offer abstraction with the ability to change business logic and data snidely as well as introduce new features.

Directly querying the database could work (though I’m not sure how a direct query from frontend code would *actually* work), but for an interface or service familiar to front end devs, security, and the ability to evolve the API, I think a tiered setup is the best-fitted approach with database, business later, APIs, and clients on top (or downstream).

Oh and there is a difference between a headless setup which implies content services of some sort (OData, RESTful, GraphQL, and so on) versus “in-memory” APIs that run within an application (think jars and dlls).